# Flow vs TypeScript action creator (Redux)

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, flowtype

I'm trying to figure out how to implement type annotation for Redux with Flow.

With TypeScript:

```
const PLAY = 'PLAY';
const RUN = 'RUN';

class PlayAction {
    readonly type = PLAY;
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}

class RunAction {
    readonly type = RUN;
    constructor(public payload: boolean) {}
}

type Actions = PlayAction | RunAction;

function dummyReducer(state: any, action: Actions) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PLAY: {
            const typeTest = action.payload; // type: string 
            break;
        }
        case RUN: {
            const typetest = action.payload; // type: boolean
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In flow documentation, I found this example: [Redux with Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/).

```
// @flow
type State = { +value: boolean };

type FooAction = { type: "FOO", foo: boolean };
type BarAction = { type: "BAR", bar: boolean };

type Action = FooAction | BarAction;

function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FOO": return { ...state, value: action.foo };
    case "BAR": return { ...state, value: action.bar };
    default:
      (action: empty);
      return state;
  }
}
```

The big problems with Flow approach:

1) use in 2 places strings, so it bad practice for miss spelling mistake.

2) is not maintainable to change the string in 2 places every time I want to change the action type value.

How can I solve this problem with Flow? Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `.type` member defined in your first example?

Comment: don't understand your question, again?

Comment: `readonly PLAY = PLAY;` really?

Comment: @LidorAvitan your first example (typescript) does not compile: `type` member is not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the some answer, but it don't work pretty much,
and again you can't work with class action creators. :/

```
type _ExtractReturn<B, F: (...args: any[]) => B> = B;
export type ExtractReturn<F> = _ExtractReturn<*, F>;
```

Action file //

```
export const SET_NAME = 'SET_NAME';
export const SET_AGE = 'SET_AGE';
const setName = (name: string) => {
    return {type: SET_NAME, payload: name}
}

const setAge = (age: number) => {
    return {type: SET_AGE, payload: age}
}
export type Actions =
    ExtractReturn<typeof setName> |
    ExtractReturn<typeof setAge>
```

[image]

**credit: Shane Osbourne**

[Redux & Flow-type](https://hackernoon.com/redux-flow-type-getting-the-maximum-benefit-from-the-fewest-key-strokes-5c006c54ec87)